# Differences between miscible and soluble

Tags: solutions, solubility

What are the differences between soluble and miscible? So far I found this (page 3 http://faculty.sites.uci.edu/chem1l/files/2011/03/D01MANmiscibility.pdf):

soluble=solid dissolves into a liquid

miscible=two liquid give rise to a homogeneous solution

Are there other differences?

Thank you.

Comment: Solubility has certain limits; miscibility doesn't. Miscible liquids can mix in any proportion. Also, welcome to Chem.SE.

Answer (score 4):

Your definition is basically correct, except using two liquids might provide for a clearer example than a solid and a liquid.  For example, diethyl ether is soluble in water to about 7% at $\mathrm{20^oC}$. This does not mean that diethyl ether is partially miscible in water, but that it it partially soluble. [This Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miscibility) provides a good distinction for miscibility:

> Miscibility is the property of substances to mix in all
>   proportions (that is, to fully dissolve in each other at any
>   concentration), forming a homogeneous solution.